# redirect in react router failed to render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

The component supposed to redirect to homepage after login but it worked before then suddenly it didnt work at all, redirect keep going back to root('/')

here's the code in **index.js** (I'm using material-kit theme):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";
import "assets/scss/material-kit-react.css?v=1.1.0";

var hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
          return <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component= 
{prop.component} />;
        })}
      </Switch>
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and here's inside index.jsx

```
var indexRoutes = [
  { path: "/login-page", name: "LoginPage", component: LoginPage },
  { path: "/register-page", name: "RegisterPage", component: RegisterPage },
  { path: "/home-page", name: "HomePage", component: Home},
  { path: "/", name: "LandingPage", component: LandingPage  }

];

export default indexRoutes;
```

here's in **login page**

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cardAnimaton: "cardHidden",
      signInEmail: "",
      signInPassword: "",
      isSignIn: false,
      errorLogin: "",
      user: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        joined: ""
      }
    };
  }

  //load user
  loadUser = (data) => {
    // update user
    this.setState({
      user: {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        joined: data.joined
      }
    })
  }


  onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ signInEmail : event.target.value})
  }

  onPasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ signInPassword : event.target.value})
  }

  //submit change
  onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/signin', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.signInEmail,
        password: this.state.signInPassword
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then( user => {
        if(user.id){
          this.loadUser(user)
          this.setState({ isSignIn: true})
        }else{
          this.setState({ errorLogin: "Please check your email and password"})
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, ...rest } = this.props;
    const { errorLogin } = this.state;

    if( this.state.isSignIn === true){
      return <Redirect 
      to="/home-page" />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className={classes.pageHeader}
        >
         <Particles className={classes.particles}
          params={ particlesOptions}
          /> 
          <div className={classes.container}>
            <GridContainer justify="center">
              <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
                <Card className={classes[this.state.cardAnimaton]}>
                  <form className={classes.form}>
                    <CardHeader className={classes.cardHeader}>
                      <h3>Login</h3>
                    </CardHeader>

                    <CardBody className={classes.cardbody}>
                      <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.signinform}>
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="email-address">Email</InputLabel>
                        <Input

                          type="email"
                          name="email-address"
                          id="email-address"
                          onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                          endAdornment={
                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                              <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor}/>
                            </InputAdornment>
                          }
                        />
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="password" className={classes.passwordlabel}>Password</InputLabel>
                        <Input
                          type="password"
                          name="password"
                          id="password"
                          onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                          endAdornment={
                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                              <LockOutline className={classes.inputIconsColor}/>
                            </InputAdornment>
                          }
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                    </CardBody>
                    {(errorLogin) ? 
                      <SnackbarContent 
                        message={errorLogin}
                        className={classNames(classes.root, classes.message)}
                      /> 
                      : "" 
                    }

                    <CardFooter className={classes.cardFooter}>
                    <p className={classes.divider}>Don't have an account?
                    <Link to='/register-page'>
                    Register
                    </Link>
                    </p>
                    <div className={classes.buttonplace}>
                      <Button className={classes.buttonsingin} size="sm" onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn} >

                        Sign In
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                    </CardFooter>

                  </form>
                </Card>
              </GridItem>
            </GridContainer>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

when i tried it directly it worked but after try to do it in login page the path change to /home-page for a moment then go back to /, I dont know why it didnt work suddenly because it worked before, there's no error

Comment: what version of react-router is installed?

Comment: @azium react router v4

Comment: your code looks like a weird mix of 3 and 4. v4 has `react-router-dom` and exports Routers directly without needing to pass history to it

Comment: @azium thats the default when im using material-kit-theme. I didnt have a problem before then idk when i try to login the path change for a brief moment then go back to ‘/‘ again even when i try to just render a component for easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a stupid mistake and a problem with `<Redirect/>`, in my home component theres a header with redirect component that supposed to go back to root page (for logout) , so everytime i try to render /home it always triggers that `<Redirect/>`

Answer (score 0):

If it take you to the `Landing Page` component whichever route you enter. You must use `exact` in your routes. In your case, It always render `"/"`corresponding component.
Try this:

```
 <Router history={hist}>
  <Switch>
    {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
      return <Route exact path={prop.path} key={key} component= 
       {prop.component} />;
    })}
  </Switch>
</Router>,
```

Let me know if issue still persists. Happy to help with this.

Comment: it works fine when i'm not trying to passing state ex `<Redirect to={{pathname: "/home-page"}}/>` but as soon as im passing state `<Redirect to={{pathname: "/home-page", state: {id: id}}} />` it goes back to root